# How to crop my App image like iPhone photo gallary

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimagepickercontroller, uiimageasset

I have developed a chat application in which user can share image.
In whatsApp when we select any image it is opening iOS default cropper .

I want to do same for my App.
Is there any way to open native croper while select image.

Comment: yes, you can develop your own coper like add a view controller and implement cropping logic in it.

Comment: Yes but i don't  think that whatsApp has developed his own cropper.They are using native.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to use iPhone photo gallery. I think Whatsapp is using it's custom cropper.